# Python oci sdk question regarding boot volume backup

Tags: python, oci-python-sdk

How do we find boot volume backups of the particular instance using python oci package

list_boot_volume_backups function will return all the backups in the compartment.

ref: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/BootVolumeBackup/ListBootVolumeBackups

- if we need to pass `source_boot_volume_backup_id` then where do we find this value
- we can use `boot_volume_id` but in that case as well `ListBootVolumes` function will list all the boot volumes in the compartment.

ref:  https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/BootVolume/ListBootVolumes

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to utilize the ListBootVolumeAttachments API, you can filter by Instance OCID, boot volume OCID, or both. ref: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/BootVolumeAttachment/ListBootVolumeAttachments

The above would return you the Boot Volume Attachment OCID which can then be used with the GetBootVolumeAttachment API to get details of the attachment between a boot volume and an instance.

ref: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/BootVolumeAttachment/GetBootVolumeAttachment

Hope this helps solve your issue!